# Certainity of a classifier

Tags: python, classifier

How to build a classifier that by default will predict that it is for class 1, but if the classifier believes with 80 certainity that it belongs to 0, it will be classed as 0. How to check how certain a classifier is on it's prediction.

Comment: Why don't you use a classifier that can export probabilities (like a Decision Tree) and make the prediction manually from there? If the probability of class 0 is > 0.8, return 0, else return 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many classifiers will give the option to get predicted probability. Then you can just put a threshold. Here is how it can be done in with sklearn:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

# Make a dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                           random_state=0, shuffle=False)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2,
                              random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)

# 1 if proba is less than 0.8, otherwise 0
predictions = 1 - (clf.predict_proba(X)[:, 0] > 0.80)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a neural network with [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) activation on the output layer, to give you values within the range [0,1]. Then you can further post-process those predictions however you like, i.e. using a threshold of 0.8 for binary classification between 0 and 1.